# Check double value null or not(if double value set in Bean class)

Tags: java, null, double

I have created a Java bean class like this

```
class BeanDemo
{
private double value;

//getter and setter
}

class myApp
{
BeanDemo beanDemo=new BeanDemo();

int val=7;
if(val<5)
{
   beanDemo.setValue(23.456);
}

double value=beanDemo.getValue(); // Always returns 0.0 if it is not set
System.out.println(value);
}
```

How can I check if that value is null? I mean if it is not set I should print something else(say **null**)

I cannot check if its **0.0** because may be i can set the value to 0.0 also.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using `Double` (the class) rather than `double` (the primitive). There's no such thing as a `null` value of type `double`:

```
class BeanDemo {
    private Double value;

    public void setValue(Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BeanDemo beanDemo = new BeanDemo();
        int val=7;
        if (val < 5) {
            beanDemo.setValue(23.456);
        }
        Double value = beanDemo.getValue(); // value will be null
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Note that you could make your setter take `double` instead of `Double` if you wanted to prevent it from becoming `null` again after being set once.

Comment: +1 for raw speed - not so much degree of difficulty :)  Might as well add that it will print `null` as suggested by OP

Comment: @Jon, Double is wrapper class for double then  Autoboxing feature need to take care of it, do not you think  curious about internal stuff how its converting to nul.

Comment: @AlpeshGediya: It's not converting anything to null. The value is null to start with.

Answer (score 7):

Use Double instead of double, this will do exactly what you want