# came across a null pointer error and I need a clearer understanding why it throws it

Tags: java

was playing around more with java and actual database values and came across an interesting null pointer error well hidden in a working code.
So there are 3 variables:

```
double x = data.getValue1; //this returns 0.0 from database 
double y = data.getValue2; //this returns a null from database
double z = 0; //variable is initialised

double z = x*y; //same as (z = 0.0 * null;)
```

now this code will work if `x` and `y` return actual values but doesn't work when this values `0.0` and `null`.

`double z` is further used in a grand total calculation. Let's say

```
double grandTotal = z + (another double value) + (another double value);
```

but double grandTotal will not work because of z.

Now I need an explanation why this happens and how better to handle the situation so that if `z` or another double value falls in that situation, it doesn't affect `grandTotal` from summing all it's values

Comment: As for *why* it happened, I have no idea as I am not clear on exactly how you get data, just what data is, etc... in this your question is very murky. As for how to avoid trouble, why not simply check for null where it might occur?

Comment: The only place an NPE can occur is the unboxing of `data.getValue2;`, not by multiplying `double`s.

Comment: Not sure how you got a `double` to be `null`?

Comment: MadProgrammer the field in that database had no value so it returned a null

Comment: Hover was playing with an old code of a friend and I'll dig deeper.. Just needed an understanding

Comment: @ollaollu What MadProgrammer means is that a primitive `double` value (the lowercase version, if you will) cannot be null. Primitive values are initialized to a 0.0 (floats and doubles) and 0 (integers, longs, etc). The object version `Double` (note the uppercase), can be null. If your `getValue2` field is of type `Double` as opposed to `double`, and it is null, then you would be getting a NPE. Otherwise, you'll get back `0.0`.

Comment: Paul Richter now I understand better. Post as answer let me accept

Comment: @ollaollu Sure, answer added. Don't feel obligated to accept mine though; accept whichever answer you feel best answers the question. Ankur-singhal also has some excellent information which may help.

Comment: @ollaollu: if this is your actual code, what is the return type of getValue1 and getValue2? If this is not your actual code, you should modify it so that it is.

Comment: jmoreno was just a simple representation but very similar to what I was working with. Have it all figured out now though. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `double` type, referred to as a *primitive*, (the lowercase version, if you will) cannot be null. Primitive values are initialized to a 0.0 (floats and doubles) and 0 (integers, longs, etc).

The object version Double (note the uppercase), can be null. If your getValue2 field is of type `Double` (as opposed to `double`), and it is null, and you attempt to assign it to a primitive value, a process called [unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) (as mentioned by [August](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2498956/august)) occurs, and you would end up with Null Pointer Exception (NPE).

Otherwise, however, if `getValue2` is in fact a `double` (note the lowercase), then you'd simply get back 0.0, and normal calculations can proceed normally from there (though perhaps not with the results you were expecting).

As Hovercraft said, simply checking for a null value might be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

`Java double` cannot be null, and cannot be compared with a Java null. (The double type is a primitive (non-reference) type and primitive types cannot be null.)

If you are getting data via `ResultSet.getDouble()`,  use `ResultSet.wasNull()`.

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090077/how-to-check-if-a-double-is-null) for more info and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747391/check-double-value-null-or-notif-double-value-set-in-bean-class).

Comment: This answer is better written as "View Stephen C's answer on [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090077/how-to-check-if-a-double-is-null)." At least give him credit for 99% of your answer.